# How did Sybok get to Nimbus III?

Tags: star-trek, the-final-frontier

At the beginning of *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, Sybok tells a man that he met that he needs to get off of Nimbus III:

> SYBOK: Join my quest.
>
> J'ONN: What is it you seek?
>
> SYBOK: What you seek. What all men have sought since time began, ...the ultimate knowledge. To find it, we'll need a starship.

How did Sybok get to the planet in the first place if he didn't have a starship?

Comment: Hitch-hiking, hm?

Comment: I always assumed he bummed a lift on a freighter or some kind of cargo vessels. His obsession is with getting hold of a ***top class starship*** (be it Romulan, Klingon or Federation), not just passage off of the planet

Comment: @Ghanima Definitely possible, although that would raise the question of why he didn't use his mind tricks on that crew and just use their starship.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Because a cargo wessel wouldn't make it through the barrier.

Comment: Nice ST:V question :) They are in style right now,  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/140569/3213

Comment: There was a comment in the movie, I forget who said it, something about people being convinced to settle the planet by overstating how good the place was.  He might have come with the settlers.

Comment: @Valorum Ah yes, the barrier that nobody ever went through, but didn't make the Enterprise even shake in the slightest. Maybe in a cargo hauler, the ship would have given the tiniest of shakes, and Sybok didn't want to risk getting space-sick ;-)

Comment: @JK. - All signs (script/novel) point to him having recently arrived.

Comment: @Thunderforge - In the script and novel the journey is rather more fraught.